# This store was previously associated with a different iCloud account with addPersistentStoreWithType for Shared Storage

Tags: core-data, icloud

And the problems continue.  Core data and iCloud are working on one device for one application, but 3 of my applications share progress data in the cloud using the same entitlements.  When I run a second application, I get the error...

This store was previously associated with a different iCloud account

During addPersistentStoreWithType, even though the iCloud account has not changed.  It's using the same ubiquitous container, so why would it come up with this message even though the iCloud account has not changed?

I am praying this is not yet another iCloud/Core Data bug.  Does anyone else have any experience of this?

Thanks
Ray

Comment: OMG.  If I create with a different database name, but use the same NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey and NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey the error goes away, but the database (newly created) is filled with the same data.

Does this mean the expectation when you are sharing iCloud core data storage between applications is for each application to have it's own database in the same storage area?  If that's the case then this error message is VERY misleading, as the iCloud account has NOT changed, only the application has changed.

Comment: This gets worse.  It seems even if each application maintains it's own database that if I don't terminate one application, the other application will not load it's persistent store.  It's like there's some kind of lock on the shared transaction logs.